# Global variables

Tags: cells, variable

I have a workbook I am writing, there are 2 cells in it and then each cell is divided into sub cells.  At the top of the first cell i made a bunch of variable assignments such as length=10, x=6, d=4, etc.  Each assignment is followed by a semicolon to suppress printing.

At no time in any cell did I clear any of the variable assignments or reassign any of the variables.  Some of the variables and the results of calculations on those variables seem to be sent to the second cell just fine, some do not.  The variables that were not available in the second cell were added to the first cell after the first cell's calculations were executed (I don't know if this makes a difference or not).  There are no blocks or modules in the wb at this time.

Any ideas as to why these variables do not seem to be available to the second cell and what I may do to make them available.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Look at `Evaluation->Notebook's Default Context` and make sure that `Global` is set.

Comment: You mention that "The variables that were not available in the second cell were added to the first cell after the first cell's calculations were executed". I think this is the origin of your problem. You need to re-execute the first cell that contains all those initializations whenever you modify them for those values to be updated with the new ones before you can use them somewhere else. It is also very useful to use the syntax coloring to your advantage: variables that still appear in blue have no value associated with them; variables that appear in black have been initialized.

Answer (score 1):

OK I think I just answered my own question while I was writing it without even knowing it.  I went into the nb and copies the variables back into the first cell, deactivated the copy of the variables in the second cell (surrounded then with (*...*) ), then then re-executed the calculations in that cell.

After re-executing the calculations the variables were available for use in the second cell.